# Css selector :hover

Tags: css

I have such css:

```
#addEmplButton:hover, #addButton:hover, #allEmpl:hover{
    background-color:#e4b9b9 ;
}
```

How can I change it for use :hover once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have multiple hover targets, you'll need to add the :hover selector to an class.

```
.hoverEvent:hover { 
     //CSS 
}
```

```css
.hoverMe:hover {
  background-color: red !important;
}

#btn1 {
  background-color: blue;
}
#btn2 {
  background-color: green;
}
#btn3 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="btn1" class="hoverMe">
  Hey There!
</div>
<div id="btn2" class="hoverMe">
  Hey There!
</div>
<div id="btn3" class="hoverMe">
  Hey There!
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it using JS **`hover()`** function to target all buttons at once.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var buttonsId = "#addEmplButton,#addButton,#allEmpl";
  $(buttonsId).hover(function() {
      $(buttonsId).addClass("afterHover");
    },
    function() {
      $(buttonsId).removeClass("afterHover");
    });

});
```

```css
#addEmplButton {
  background-color: blue;
}
#addButton {
  background-color: green;
}
#allEmpl {
  background-color: yellow;
}
/*Hover style here*/

.afterHover {
  background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="addEmplButton">Add Employee</button>
<button id="addButton">Add</button>
<button id="allEmpl">All Employee</button>
```

Comment: The OP asked for the `:hover` selector, which is used in css, not for a jQuery or JavaScript Solution. But a nice other solution.

Comment: @Dome - accepted, but we can't achieve this with CSS only.

Comment: Look at the answer above. It is CSS only.